# Insert GetPivotData formula through VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a GetPivotData formula into some cells.
There are up to 7 pivot tables to get the data, so I need to do it dynamically:

```
Function Formula(KPI As String, FilaTD As Integer, ColumnaTD As Integer, Filtro1 As String, _
    Simple As Boolean, Optional Filtro2 As String)

    If Simple = True Then
        Formula = "IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(" & Comillas & KPI & Comillas & ",'TDReport Control Desk'!R" & _
        FilaTD & "C" & ColumnaTD & "," & Filtro1 & ",RC2),0)"
    Else
        Formula = "IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(" & Comillas & KPI & Comillas & ",'TDReport Control Desk'!R" & _
        FilaTD & "C" & ColumnaTD & "," & Filtro1 & ",RC2),GETPIVOTDATA(" & Comillas & KPI & Comillas & _
        ",'TDReport Control Desk'!R" & FilaTD & "C" & ColumnaTD & "," & Filtro2 & ",RC2))"
    End If

End Function
```

The string called "Comillas" is just a constant:

```
Public Const Comillas As String = """"""
```

I call this function like this:

```
FormulaPrevisionAtenMesCentro = Formula(KPI2, FilaTDOffCentro, ColumnaTDOffCentro, "Centro", True)

FormulaPrevisionAtenDiaCentro = Formula(KPI2, _
FilaTDOffDiaCentro, ColumnaTDOffDiaCentro, "Centro", True)

FormulaPrevisionAtenMes = Formula(KPI2, _
FilaTDOffMes, ColumnaTDOffMes, "Modo2", False, "Modo3")

FormulaPrevisionAtenDia = Formula(KPI2, _
FilaTDOffDia, ColumnaTDOffDia, "Modo2", False, "Modo3")

FormulaKPIMes = Formula(KPI, _
FilaTDOffMes, ColumnaTDOffMes, "Modo2", False, "Modo3")

FormulaKPIMesCentro = Formula(KPI, FilaTDOffCentro, ColumnaTDOffCentro, "Centro", True)

FormulaKPIDia = Formula(KPI, _
FilaTDOffDia, ColumnaTDOffDia, "Modo2", False, "Modo3")

FormulaKPIDiaCentro = Formula(KPI, FilaTDOffDiaCentro, ColumnaTDOffDiaCentro, "Centro", True)
```

My problem is within the *Comillas* thing. If I use it, it will throw a VBA error. If I don't use it, the formula will get inserted but won't work, because the field I'm asking for, won't be between " ".

Comment: Side note: If Simple = True  can just be written as If Simple

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `Public Const Comillas As String = """"`?

Comment: @Rory That's probably the issue with the code, not a typo (although as I was typing this, I realized that may have been how you meant your comment).

Comment: @Mistella Yes, that is what I meant. :)

Comment: Will your formula work if you use single quotes instead of double quotes?  That way you can write `Formula = "IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA('" & KPI & "','TDReport ...`

Comment: Thank you  @Rory that worked... when I was recording the macro VBA put the strings like ""Whatever"" so I thought I had to input 2 "" on each side... turns out that didn't need too. How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: @Damian, Rory added his comment as an answer w/slight explanation. If you accept his answer (by clicking the checkmark next to it), other people will see that this question has an accepted answer.

Comment: Done! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
Public Const Comillas As String = """"
```

since you only want the formula to contain a single quotation mark on each side of the value. You only need to double them up when putting a literal quoted string inside a formula string, not when concatenating it in.